# Message Dialogue in Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

How do I show a Dialogue Box from a Thread? I have a Swing App that executes set of Actions in Background. After completion of Processing I need to show a Message Dialog Box. The main Swing App is "Always On Top".

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
```

doesn't show the message box above. Well I need to write the above line in the run method of a thread.

More Data:

The thread is created by extending the Thread Class. The start method is called from EDT of a button click.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call it using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, such that it is forwarded for execution to the UI thread:

```
// thread run method
public void run() {

    ...

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
           }
        });
}
```

Comment: The thread is created by extending the Thread Class. The start method is called from EDT of a button click. So how do I achieve what you said "Try to call it using SwingUtilities.invokeLater, such that it is forwarded for execution to the UI thread"

Comment: As you see in my code, just put that call to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` in the `run` method of your thread.

Comment: that's the same as my code. No effect. The MessageDialog is generated but is shown behind the main swing form.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the reference to the main app instead of `null` in the `showMessageDialog()` call.

Also make sure it's called in EDT. Use for example `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

Comment: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ClassName.this, "message"));`


the prefix ClassName is necessary instead of "this" alone to avoid reference confusion with another inner class

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke [JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) or [JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInternalMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) from `Thread`, but you have test for `isEventDispatchThread` or by wrapping into `invokeLater` or `invokeAndWait` (depends of return value back to the `Thread`),

Swing si single threaded and all output to the Swing GUI must be done on EDT (more in the [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)), otherwise you can see only `thin toolbar` with `close button` and without some contents nor `JComponents`